# Makefile opening in emacs, how to change?

Tags: filenames, editors

I updated Ubuntu (technically Lubuntu) and now `Makefile` is opening in `emacs`. It used to open in `leafpad`. How to set it back? I checked the usual places, but I couldn't find any references in the files to `Makefile` or `emacs`. It's like some kind of voodoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` and then select `leafpad` from the available options?  If it's not listed you could try re-installing `leafpad`.  Perhaps when `emacs` was installed, it superseded your previous default editor.